# AWS-Cognito: How to sign in user with email or username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

During AWS Cogito User Pool there are two options for how to let users sign in. One of them is

**Username - Users can use a username and optionally multiple alternatives to sign up and sign in.**

**Also allow sign in with verified email address**

I have selected the above and while testing it using aws-amplify I always get `__type: "NotAuthorizedException"
message: "Incorrect username or password."` if I try to sign in with email but it works fine when I try to sign in with the username.

Here is my signin method

```
Auth.signIn(email, password)
  .then(r => {
    setLoggedIn(true);
  })
  .catch(r => {
    setLoggedIn(false);
  })
```

};

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I've recently had this problem and had to figure it out. When you have a user in your user pool **that does not have the email_verified** set to True, the *Auth.signIn* method will only work with that user's username.

Not only that, but the *Auth.forgotPassword* method won't send the code to the user's e-mail. There's possibly more interactions like these.

Make sure you **confirm your user's email**, that's all!

If you are using a backend to create your users, you can simply do this by:

```
const signUpParams = {
  UserPoolId: "YOUR_USER_POOL_ID",
  TemporaryPassword: "TEMP_PW",
  Username: "username",
  UserAttributes: [
    {
      Name: 'email',
      Value: "USER_EMAIL",
    },
    {
      Name: 'email_verified',
      Value: 'true',
    },
  ],
};

const { User } = await cognitoService.adminCreateUser(signUpParams).promise();
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error that `email_verified` property cannot be mutated. But the `email` is set correctly from `UserAttributes`

Comment: @IlyaKushlianski weird. Did you try with adminCreateUser or adminUpdateUser? Both work here on each end here. If you are trying to update from the frontend (eg using Amplify's Auth class), then you should check your app client's permission on attributes (tho i dont know if this is one prop that can be changed via client)

Comment: I think that was because I am using `SignUpCommand` instead of `AdminSignUpCommand`

Comment: @IlyaKushlianski thats it!

Answer (score 0):

My vuex store action for login:
You may need to set the attribute name to `username`

```
async login({ commit },{ email, password }) {
    const user =  await Auth.signIn({ username: email, password });
    commit('set', user)
    return user;
  },
```